# T-SQL query table to re-sort data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

I am trying to come up with a means of translating the following data:

| ID | F1 | F2 | F3 | F1% | F2% | F3% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | ID1F1Value | ID1F2Value | ID1F3Value | ID1F1%Value | ID1F2%Value | ID1F3%Value |
| ID2 | ID2F1Value | ID2F2Value | ID2F3Value | ID2F1%Value | ID2F2%Value | ID2F3%Value |

into the following

| ID1 | F | % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | ID1F1Value | ID1F1%Value |
| ID1 | ID1F2Value | ID1F2%Value |
| ID1 | ID1F3Value | ID1F3%Value |
| ID2 | ID2F1Value | ID2F1%Value |
| ID2 | ID2F2Value | ID2F2%Value |
| ID2 | ID2F3Value | ID2F3%Value |

I am considering exporting it to EXCEL to run a VBA to process it after hours of trying to figure this out using SQL... Hoping that a SQL master could enlighten me with an amazing solution.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

**You are looking for an *unpivot* not a *pivot*.**

You can use `CROSS APPLY (VALUES` to unpivot.

```sql
SELECT
   t.ID,
   v.F,
   v.[%]
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    (F1, [F1%]),
    (F2, [F2%]),
    (F3, [F3%])
) v (F, [%]);
```

You could also use the `UNPIVOT` operator in some situations but it can be less flexible.

Comment: Thank you very much. Another amazing solution !

Answer (score 2):

One approach uses a union all:

```sql
SELECT ID AS ID1, F1 AS F, [F1%] AS [%]
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, F2, [F2%]
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, F3, [F3%];
```

Comment: Why scan the table three times?

Comment: This is amazing ! So simple and elegant! I have a long way to go in my SQL journey.